# Web SQL - Why is my Web SQL database got deleted when I clear browsing data on Chrome (not like evercookie)?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-history, evercookie

I'm populating an `API` like [samy's evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/). Currently my own `API` uses the following methods for storing cookies in the client's browser:

`- Standard HTTP cookie

 - HTML5 session storage

 - HTML5 local storage

 - HTML5 Web SQL database

 - HTML5 IndexedDB`

When it comes to implementing `Web SQL database`, I referenced (quite carefully) from [samy's github repository](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie) and some other resources. My `Web SQL database` works well with the initializing, adding or removing data tasks.
But one thing that make me confuse is that although my implementation of mine and samy's `evercookie` on `Web SQL database` is nearly the same, when I use `Google Chrome` to Clear browsing data (all of them), the results are different (I checked them by go to `Chrome Developer Tools > Resources tab > Web SQL`):

- On [my site](http://52.74.201.171:3000/), the Web SQL database is totally gone!
- On [samy's site](http://samy.pl/evercookie/), **the Web SQL still there!**  This is one of the reason why the cookie on samy's page can recover on the next page load.

I read `samy's evercookie` code carefully and the `Web SQL` implementation are almost the same **(this is [my code](https://github.com/thaisonle94/ts-zombie-cookie/blob/master/public/javascripts/ts-zcookie.js#L79-L105))**, so I completely have no idea why the `Web SQL` data on his page doesn't get deleted when I `Clear browsing data`.
I've been stuck at this for hours, so I really hope you guys can help ! Thanks so much in advanced !